# How to run a task on a specific thread which is active?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, swing

Is there a way I can do a similar task like the android OS or java AWT thread where a task is run on a particular thread regardless of which thread of which thread the method was called from e.g. repaint().

```
private Thread thread;
  public void startThread(){ //method which start's my thread
    thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
      doSomething();
    });
    thread.start()
  }

  public void submitTask(Runnable runnable){
    //run the runnable task on the thread "thread"
  }
```

How can I achieve something like this, on a situation where I have more then one active thread

Comment: Did the answer work out for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How I've dealt with this scenario before is to create a work queue and a thread which processes tasks that get added to it. So any thread can add a work item to the queue and the same thread will process it regardless of what thread added the work item.

```
 public class MyClass {

    private LinkedBlockingQueue<MyTask> myTaskProcessingQueue;

    public MyClass() {
        myTaskProcessingQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<MyTask>();
        new MyTaskWorker().start();
    }

    public void processTask(MyTask myTask) {
        myTaskProcessingQueue.put(myTask);
    }

    private class MyTaskWorker extends Thread {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    processMyTask(myTaskProcessingQueue.take());
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                    // handle it
                }
            }
        }

        private void processMyTask(MyTask myTask) {
            // do work
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The work queue is the right solution (and in fact that's what happens with AWT repaint/paint behind the scenes, along with all other UI event dispatching). However the implementation here is unnecessarily complex, as LinkedBlockingQueue provides thread-safe put/offer and take operations which will block if necessary. These operations eliminate the need to synchronize on the queue and invoke wait and notify.

Comment: It worked thanks, strange how I tried a similar method but using my own queue and it failed

Comment: @thewmo Good call on the put and take operations. Makes it much cleaner. I've updated my answer - should make it more useful